# java assignment in char

Tags: java, char

I am learning java and the answer of one question seems to be wrong:
question: Which of the following are legal?

```
char c = 0x1234;//A
char c = \u1234;//B
char c = '\u1234';//C
```

in the book the answer is C, but I think it should be both A and C. Anyone please verify that for me?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: (A) is perfectly legal.

Comment: Numbers aren't characters.

Comment: Just B is incorrect, missing single quotes.

Answer (score 6):

Both A and C are correct

```
char a = 0x1234;
```

The literal `0x1234` is a hex integer literal. Its value fits in the `char` primitive type, so it is valid;

```
char b = \u1234;//B
```

Is not valid notation and so won't compile.

```
char c = '\u1234';
```

[`char` is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>   a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>   65,535 inclusive).

So it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

char c = 0x1234;//A -- Correct

as it's value begins with 0X it is a valid hexadecimal value. Hence Correct.

char c = \u1234;//B --- Incorrect

Not a valid u code, as it's not surrounded with''.

char c = '\u1234';//C -- Correct

it is valid u code and is correctly surrounded by '', hence it is correct too.

Comment: Why? Explain your answer

Comment: char c = 0x1234; , as it's value begins with 0X it is a valid hexadecimal value. Hence Correct.     char c = '\u1234';   it is valid u code and is correctly surrounded by '', hence it is correct too.

Comment: You should explain it in the answer itself - not everyone will read the comments